# Seeking Assistance: AssetPack Resource.Load Issue with Default Compression in Fast-Follow

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-app-bundle

I need help with an issue related to AssetPack Resource.Load during fast-follow. When I use the Default compression algorithm to generate the app bundle, the load operation returns null. However, everything works fine when I use LZ4 compression. Is there a limitation on using Default compression with Fast-Follow, or could there be another underlying problem?

When using AAB, if I generate the app bundle with the Default compression algorithm, the AssetPack Resource.Load returns null during fast-follow. However, if I use LZ4 compression, the loading works correctly. Is there a restriction on using Default compression with Fast-Follow or is there another issue?

Comment: Unity:2022.3.10f